# Rails 4 form that saves parent id values in a children record in a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.3

i'm developing in Rails 4 with bootstrap rails forms and i'm trying to make a form that saves a product to a table. The product has many inputs and the input could belong to many products. The DB is postgres.

My main issue here is to save the product_id and the input_id to a join table I've created, named "productinput". this could be an example of what i'm trying to accomplish:

productinput table values example to generate each time i generate a new product with many inputs selected from a checkbox select:

product_id: 1  input_id: 1
product_id: 1  input_id: 2
product_id: 1  input_id: 3
product_id: 1  input_id: 4

I've done most of the configuration in my app. please take a look:

```
**productinput model**

class Productinput < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :input, inverse_of: :productinputs
belongs_to :product, inverse_of: :productinputs

validates_presence_of :user_id
validates_presence_of :input_id
validates_presence_of :product_id
end

**product model**

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :productinputs, inverse_of: :product, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :inputs, :through => :productinputs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :inputs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :productinputs, :allow_destroy => true

has_many :clientproducts, inverse_of: :product
has_many :worktasks, inverse_of: :product

validates_presence_of :user_id

accepts_nested_attributes_for :clientproducts, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :worktasks
end

**input model**

class Input < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :productinputs, inverse_of: :input, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :products, :through => :productinputs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :productinputs, :allow_destroy => true

has_many :inputproviders, inverse_of: :input

validates_presence_of :user_id

accepts_nested_attributes_for :inputproviders
end
```

Then the product form i'd like to have updated with the Input field to add inputs dinamically with a multiple select:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for( @product, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2 hide", control_col: "col-sm-12", label_errors: true) do |f| %>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.alert_message "Please fix the errors below." %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <%= f.text_field :name, hide_label: true, placeholder: "Name", icon: "tag" %>
      <%= f.text_field :description, hide_label: true, placeholder: "Description", icon: "align-justify" %>
      <%= f.text_field :stock, hide_label: true, placeholder: "Stock", icon: "book" %>
      <%= f.text_field :price, hide_label: true, placeholder: "Price", icon: "usd" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <%= f.submit "Submit Product", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                products_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

i've tried cocoon, nested_form, formtastic, simple_form gems, many tutorials and more that 2 weeks investigating this and i still don't understand how can i manage to do this, would you give me a hand please ?

Thanks,

Comment: If I were you I'd pick a solution that you want to go with and try to show us the minimum of code to reproduce that problem. Nobody wants to read through lots of generic "what I want" text in conjunction with lots of code.

Comment: Just because you don't like the answer doesn't mean it's not productive. You can always ask another question that is more specific, and I bet you that your chances of getting help are so much greater. Also, try indenting your code properly, small things like that matter. OR, keep doing what you are doing, but then don't blame people like me for not helping you.

Comment: Was just trying to offer you some word of advice. If you're going to continue in this industry, you will find out what I mean eventually.

Comment: sorry dan sbout what i said before. but i didin't know how to solve this problem, even how to start. i figured out that rails and activerecord in conjunction with simple form, solved my issue and i got the join table records working. the solution is described below.

Comment: Good to hear that you solved it, and shared your solution with the rest. That might help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i manage to create children records in the join table from the parent form view:

**Models:**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :productinputs, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :inputs, through: :productinputs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :productinputs, :allow_destroy => true

    has_many :clientproducts, inverse_of: :product
    has_many :worktasks, inverse_of: :product

    validates_presence_of :user_id
end

class Productinput < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :input

    #validates_presence_of :user_id
    #validates_presence_of :input_id
    #validates_presence_of :product_id
end

class Input < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :productinputs
    has_many :products, through: :productinputs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :productinputs, :allow_destroy => true

    has_many :inputproviders, inverse_of: :input

    validates_presence_of :user_id

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :inputproviders
end
```

**Controller:**

Key here, the :inputs_ids[] fills up with an array of input elements from the "check_box_tag "product[input_ids][]"" in the form:

```
def product_params
  parameters = params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :stock, :price, :input_ids => [], productinputs_attributes: [:user_id, :quantity])
  parameters[:user_id] = current_user.id
  parameters
end
```

**Form:**

```
<%= simple_form_for @product, defaults: { input_html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } } do |f| %>
    <div class="row"> <%= f.error_notification id: 'user_error_message', class: 'form_error' %>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Product Name', error: 'Username is mandatory, please specify one', label: false %>
        <%= f.input :description, placeholder: 'Enter Description', label: false %>
        <%= f.input :stock, placeholder: 'Stock', label: false %>
        <%= f.input :price, placeholder: 'Price', label: false %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <%= hidden_field_tag "product[input_ids][]", nil %>
        <% Input.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).each do |input| %>
            <%= check_box_tag "product[input_ids][]", input.id,
                              @product.input_ids.include?(input.id), id: dom_id(input) %>
            <%= label_tag dom_id(input), input.name %><br>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                  products_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Hope this helps anyone who has the same issue that i did.

Sorry if some people didn't understand what i was looking for.

P.S: just to let you know, i could simplify the multiple checkbox with simple form from this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "product[input_ids][]", nil %>
<% Input.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).each do |input| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "product[input_ids][]", input.id, @product.input_ids.include?(input.id), id: dom_id(input) %>
    <%= label_tag dom_id(input), input.name %><br>
<% end %>
```

to this:

```
<%= f.association :inputs, :as => :check_boxes %>
```